# Game vs fowl vs domestic bird

Tags: word-difference

As I understand, a bird can be:

1. Game or a game bird can be any bird that is hunted anywhere with a rifle (for example). Game lives in the open (in wild conditions) hunted by hunters.
2. If a duck is shot by a hunter, it's game.  If it is grown or bred on a farm, it's a domestic bird.
   So, if we breed a chicken for meals, is it poultry or fowl?  If we shoot it while hunting, it's game.  Am I correct?

Comment: Small point: game birds are hunted with shotguns, not rifles.

Comment: Fun fact: some people use small caliber rifles to shoot ptarmigan.

Answer (score 1):

**game** in this sense is not countable, nor is **poultry** : we do not refer to an individual game animal as **a game** <sup>NO</sup>, or to a chicken as **a poultry** <sup>NO</sup>.

These words refer to the *class*.

**game** are *wild* animals hunted for food or sport.

**fowl** can be wild or domesticated.

**poultry** are domesticated.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations are for poultry.

Answer (score 0):

You’re broadly correct. But you mean to say *domesticated* (i.e. *not wild*) where you’ve written *domestic* (which means *not foreign*). And *fowl* is broadly synonymous with “bird”, especially the edible kind. In fact, *fowl* is often used as a synonym for *poultry*: you’ll see it on older more traditional menus as a category, for example. But it’s also used to refer to living birds, usually game birds, but not always.

<sub>(transcribed from comment)</sub>